# An exercise in Artin's Algebra

Tags: group-theory

The exercise is from Chapter 9 "Linear group".

> - Q4.8b: Let $W$ be the real vector space of Hermitian 2 x 2 matrices. Prove that the function $\langle A,A'\rangle =\det(A+A')-\det(A)-\det(A')$ is a bilinear form on $W$, and that its signature is $(3,1)$.

Here signature $(3,1)$ means the matrix of that bilinear form is $$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1& 0  \\
 0 & 0& 0 & -1
 \end{pmatrix}\;.$$

(Indeed, I have calculated the signature should be $(1,3)$, i.e. the matrix of the form should be $$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -1& 0  \\
 0 & 0& 0 & -1
 \end{pmatrix}$$ so I'm thinking about the question missed a negetive sign in the bilinear form i.e. it should be $\langle A,A'\rangle =-[\det(A+A')-\det(A)-\det(A')]$, then we can have signature $(3,1)$, am I right or not?)

Comment: What does real hermitian mean ? Symmetric ? Then it has dimension 3.

Comment: That mean a complex 2 by 2 matrix, in which its complex conjugate is equal to itself. You can find out it is of dimension 4 by expressing the complex number into real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Any ideas or hints are welcome!

Comment: I agree you have $3$ times $-$ and one $+$.

Comment: Yes, since I'm following the definition of Artin of signature on p.240. If it is the case, so we assume its signature is (1,3) first. Then for part(c), how one can define a homomorphism from SL_2(C) to O_{1,3} whose kernel is {±I}, may I some hints if this question?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest to calculate the quadratic form associated. This is just

$$\frac{1}{2}B(A,A)=\det A$$

For an arbitrary element of your vector space write it in the form

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}x+y&z+iw\\
z-iw&x-y\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $$\det A=x^2-y^2-z^2-w^2$$